# Rust lifetime annotation in tree type

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

I'm new in rust community
I'm writing a B tree implementation and have problems with refs

```rust
#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Node<'a, T: PartialOrd + Clone> {
    leaf: bool,
    count: usize,
    keys: Vec<T>,
    children: Vec<&'a mut Node<'a, T>>,
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
impl<'a, T: PartialOrd + Clone> Node<'a, T> {
    fn is_full(&self, index: usize, t: usize) -> bool {
        self.children[index].count == 2 * t - 1
    }

    fn split(&'a mut self, i: usize, t: usize) {
        let left = self.children[i];
        let ref mut right = Node::<T>::empty();

        right.leaf = left.leaf;
        right.count = t - 1;

        for j in 0..t - 1 {
            right.keys[j] = right.keys[j + t].clone()
        }

        if !left.leaf {
            for j in 0..t {
                right.children[j] = left.children[j + t];
            }
        }
    }

    fn insert_nonfull(&'a mut self, value: T, t: usize) {
        if self.leaf {
            let mut i = self.count - 1;

            while i > 0 && self.keys[i] >= value {
                self.keys[i] = self.keys[i - 1].clone();
                i -= 1;
            }

            self.keys[i] = value;
            self.count += 1;

            return;
        }

        let mut i = self.count - 1;

        while i > 0 && self.keys[i] >= value {
            i -= 1;
        }

        if self.is_full(i, t) {
            self.split(i, t);
            if value > self.keys[i]  {
                i += 1
            }
        }

        self.children[i].insert_nonfull(value, t);
    }


    fn empty() -> Self {
        return Node::<'a, T> {
            children: vec![],
            keys: vec![],
            count: 0,
            leaf: false
        }
    }

    fn leaf() -> Self {
        return Node::<'a, T> {
            children: vec![],
            keys: vec![],
            count: 0,
            leaf: true,
        };
    }
}

struct BTree<'a, T: PartialOrd + Clone> {
    root: Node<'a, T>,
    t: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let mut leaf = Node::<u32>::leaf();
}
```

can you help with:

1. what type should I use for `children` declaration in Node? I tried Box like in [Rust docs example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html), but it failed.
2. can I use single lifetime annotation in `impl` block?
3. how can I make private scope? I tried `pub(self)` or `pub(super`)

cargo check:

```
    Checking rust v0.1.0 (/Users/v8tenko/rust)
warning: unused variable: `leaf`
  --> src/main.rs:90:13
   |
90 |     let mut leaf = Node::<u32>::leaf();
   |             ^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_leaf`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Box<Node<T>>>`
  --> src/main.rs:28:37
   |
28 |                 right.children[j] = right.children[j + t]
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Box<Node<T>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src/main.rs:90:9
   |
90 |     let mut leaf = Node::<u32>::leaf();
   |         ----^^^^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
warning: `rust` (bin "rust") generated 2 warnings
error: could not compile `rust` due to previous error; 2 warnings emitted
```

code with Box

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Node<T: PartialOrd + Clone> {
    leaf: bool,
    count: usize,
    keys: Vec<T>,
    children: Vec<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
impl<T: PartialOrd + Clone> Node<T> {
    fn is_full(&self, index: usize, t: usize) -> bool {
        self.children[index].count == 2 * t - 1
    }

    fn split(&mut self, i: usize, t: usize) {
        let ref mut left = self.children[i];
        let ref mut right = Node::<T>::empty();

        right.leaf = left.leaf;
        right.count = t - 1;

        for j in 0..t - 1 {
            right.keys[j] = right.keys[j + t].clone()
        }

        if !left.leaf {
            for j in 0..t {
                right.children[j] = right.children[j + t]
            }
        }
    }

    fn insert_nonfull(&mut self, value: T, t: usize) {
        if self.leaf {
            let mut i = self.count - 1;

            while i > 0 && self.keys[i] >= value {
                self.keys[i] = self.keys[i - 1].clone();
                i -= 1;
            }

            self.keys[i] = value;
            self.count += 1;

            return;
        }

        let mut i = self.count - 1;

        while i > 0 && self.keys[i] >= value {
            i -= 1;
        }

        if self.is_full(i, t) {
            self.split(i, t);
            if value > self.keys[i]  {
                i += 1
            }
        }

        self.children[i].insert_nonfull(value, t);
    }


    fn empty() -> Self {
        return Node {
            children: vec![],
            keys: vec![],
            count: 0,
            leaf: false
        }
    }

    fn leaf() -> Self {
        return Node {
            children: vec![],
            keys: vec![],
            count: 0,
            leaf: true,
        };
    }
}

struct BTree<T: PartialOrd + Clone> {
    root: Node<T>,
    t: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let mut leaf = Node::<u32>::leaf();
}
```

Comment: They're indeed unused, no public code uses them.

Comment: You should use `Box` for that. What was your attempt with `Box`? How did it fail?

Comment: Chayim Friedman, thank you.

Comment: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Box<Node<T>>>`
move occurs because value has type `Box<Node<T>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait. I don't want to copy Node

Comment: Please update the question with the code you've tried and the full error from `cargo check`, not in a comment.

Comment: Please post the full error message from `cargo check`, not your IDE, as well as the code that caused this failure.

Comment: Now you posted the error, but **still not the code**.

Comment: Using `ref mut` in variable declarations is a bad idea: it will make people scratch their heads against your code. Use simple `let x = &mut v;`.

Comment: I'm failing to understand your code. Why do you fill `right.keys` and `right.values` with values from after, which have not been yet initialized? Did you mean to still them from `self`?

Comment: yes, initialize from self

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in `Vec` that does exactly what you want - cut a `Vec` and leave part of the elements, while putting the rest of the elements in another `Vec` - [`Vec::split_off()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_off):

```rust
fn split(&mut self, i: usize, t: usize) {
    let ref mut left = self.children[i];
    let ref mut right = Node::<T>::empty();

    right.leaf = left.leaf;
    right.count = t - 1;

    right.keys = self.keys.split_off(t);

    if !left.leaf {
        right.children = self.children.split_off(t);
    }
}
```